# Labels covering point layer symbols QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis-3, point, labeling, symbology, z-index

I am encountering a problem with label placement in QGIS 3.28. Specifically, the elevation contour labels in my project are covering the symbols of another point layer, even though I have arranged the layers so that the contour vector layer is positioned behind the point symbol layer in the layer panel.

[image]

Despite trying to adjust the label placement by setting the z-value to -1 or other values, the labels continue to cover the symbols. I don't want to change the position of labels or make them disappear using "Obstacles weight"; I just want to show labels behind the symbols as arranged in the layer panel.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in QGIS 3.28?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know label are Always drawn on top of feature symbol : feature symbol are drawn (following layer panel order then for each layer the feature rendering order if defined) then label are drawn on top (you may set the label z index to order label between them).

To have text below feature you may use text annotation, as annotation are stored in annotation layer you can place them where you want in the layer panel (https://north-road.com/2021/10/21/introducing-annotation-layers-in-qgis-3-22/).

You either will need to manually create each text annotation (convenient only if you have few annotation) or try the [Convert Labels plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ConvertLabels/) (I have no experience with it so I can't say if it's good or not) to get from label to annotation.

The obvious disadvantage of using annotation rather than label is that you loose the automated placement of the labelling engine so if you go this way made sure to have fully defined all your labelling option before creating the annotation

Comment: It is impossible to make all the values of elevation manually. This plugin doesn't work, tried both of options: 1-Point vector layer for labels (save the labels in gpkg) , 2- Text at point on annotation layer.

Comment: Then I would suggest to ask another question : "How to convert labels to an annotation layer", hopefully somebody will be able to help with that (unfortunately I can't). Aso could you explain what didn't work with the plugin ?

Comment: Firstly I converted the labels with the plugin as a point layer gpkg. The output was a point layer with same symbology as line contour layer labels only in which labels didn't appear (I don't know why) and there was too many points (maybe was possible labeling position of the line layer). Then I used  -Text at point on annotation layer directly at the contour line layer and to the point gpkg layer which I converted before where nothing happens.